# How to add Mongodb atlas CDN to firewall?

Tags: mongodb, azure, firewall, atlas

Hi All Today I got mail from mongodb
That I need to add mongodb atlas Content Delivery Network CDN to my firewall.
Any body knows how to do that
what exactly I need to add in firewall.

MongoDB Atlas has blocked the CDN Url.
Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through [this troubleshooting guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#attempting-to-connect-from-behind-a-firewall)?

> If your organization uses a firewall, add the following Atlas CDN host
> to the firewall's allow list to prevent issues accessing the Atlas UI:
> https://assets.mongodb-cdn.com/.